# React js image uploder code with firebase cloud storage gives error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating a instagram clone and I have made it with react js and database is cloud firestore, and using Cloud Storage for storing images.

I am getting error in ImageUpload.js when I am clicking on upload button and progress bar does not show any progress in console.

The folowing error is shown:

> FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `on` at inde…Expected one of the event types: [state_changed].", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}

code of **ImageUpload.js**

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Post from "./Post";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import ImageUpload from "./ImageUpload";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);

  const [posts, setsPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // UseEffect ::--> Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //user has logged in....
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        //user has logged out....
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      //perform some cleanup actions
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [user, username]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code runs
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      //every time a new post is added,this code firebase
      setsPosts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          post: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        return authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const signIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));

    setOpenSignIn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {user?.displayName ? (
        <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
      ) : (
        <h3>Sorry you need to login to upload</h3>
      )}

      <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              placeholder="usermane"
              type="text"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signUp}>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Modal open={openSignIn} onClose={() => setOpenSignIn(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>

            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signIn}>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>

      {user ? (
        <Button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Log Out</Button>
      ) : (
        <div className="app__loginContainer">
          <Button onClick={() => setOpenSignIn(true)}>Sign In</Button>

          <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Sign Up</Button>
        </div>
      )}

      {/* <h1>Lets built ig-clone with React</h1> */}
      {posts.map(({ id, post }) => (
        <Post
          key={id}
          username={post.username}
          caption={post.caption}
          imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        />
      ))}

      {/* <Post
        username="cleverqazi"
        caption="WoW is works"
        imageUrl="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/446356636710363136/OYIaJ1KK_400x400.png"
      />
      <Post
        username="ssssangha"
        caption="Dope"
        imageUrl="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687266197-6c66c083b39c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687266197-6c66c083b39c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
      />
      <Post
        username="amatsf"
        caption="This is fun Project"
        imageUrl="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600872844932-f95ce063b94c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
      />
      Post */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

code from **App.js**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Post from "./Post";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import ImageUpload from "./ImageUpload";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);

  const [posts, setsPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // UseEffect ::--> Runs a piece of code based on a specific condition

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //user has logged in....
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        //user has logged out....
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      //perform some cleanup actions
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [user, username]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code runs
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      //every time a new post is added,this code firebase
      setsPosts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          post: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        return authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const signIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));

    setOpenSignIn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {user?.displayName ? (
        <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
      ) : (
        <h3>Sorry you need to login to upload</h3>
      )}

      <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              placeholder="usermane"
              type="text"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signUp}>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Modal open={openSignIn} onClose={() => setOpenSignIn(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>

            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signIn}>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          className="app__headerImage"
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo-2x.png/1b47f9d0e595.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>

      {user ? (
        <Button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Log Out</Button>
      ) : (
        <div className="app__loginContainer">
          <Button onClick={() => setOpenSignIn(true)}>Sign In</Button>

          <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Sign Up</Button>
        </div>
      )}

      {/* <h1>Lets built ig-clone with React</h1> */}
      {posts.map(({ id, post }) => (
        <Post
          key={id}
          username={post.username}
          caption={post.caption}
          imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        />
      ))}

      {/* <Post
        username="cleverqazi"
        caption="WoW is works"
        imageUrl="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/446356636710363136/OYIaJ1KK_400x400.png"
      />
      <Post
        username="ssssangha"
        caption="Dope"
        imageUrl="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687266197-6c66c083b39c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687266197-6c66c083b39c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
      />
      <Post
        username="amatsf"
        caption="This is fun Project"
        imageUrl="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600872844932-f95ce063b94c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
      />
      Post */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

code of **firebase.js**

```
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseapp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAOozRFYMCWRQYQ4DZg19LB-8naEiL7WDvWE",
  authDomain: "instagram-clone-react-cc16f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://instagram-react-cc16f.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "instagram-clone-react-cc6f",
  storageBucket: "instagram-clone-react-cc16f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "602134433443",
  appId: "1:602189635954:web:d2d9096d64345349101bdeb",
  measurementId: "G-CW4M24VATZ",
});

const db = firebaseapp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

Comment: Which line of code is that error referring to?  I don't see it here.  In fact, I don't see any code that deals with Cloud Storage, as the error message suggests.

Comment: I think its in the catch line of ImageUpload.js

Comment: The only catches you have are against Firebase Auth APIs.  I still don't see any code here that deals with Cloud Storage.

Comment: I have added firebase.js in the description of question

Comment: I hope the api key has been changed as its now indexed on Google from posting here along with your dev urls

Comment: I changed it now thanks for telling me

Answer (score 0):

You must add handleUpload to the button you send the picture.

```js
function ImageUpload({ username }) {
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        //progress function
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(progress);
      },
      (error) => {
        //error function
        console.log(error);
        alert(error.message);
      },
      () => {
        //complete function
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            //post image inside db
            db.collection("posts").add({
              timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              caption: caption,
              imageUrl: url,
              username: username,
            });
            setProgress(0);
            setCaption("");
            setImage(null);
          });
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/*
        -  I want to have ...
       -  Caption input
       -  File picture*/}
      <progress value={progress} max="100" />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a caption..."
        onChange={(event) => setCaption(event.target.value)}
        value={caption}
      />
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <Button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```